# Error saving image file: No such file or directory

Tags: android, image, download, server

I am facing the following error while downloading images:

```
Error saving image file: /storage/emulated/0/InstagramFavouriteshttps:/scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/11371164_841887855880940_277042645_n.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Below is my code:

```
private boolean storeImage(Bitmap imageData, String filename) {
        //get path to external storage (SD card)
       //String iconsStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myAppDir/myImages/"

        File newfile = new File(rootPath);
        //create storage directories, if they don't exist
        //rootFileDirectory.mkdirs();
        System.out.println("IMAGES DOWNLOADED IN FOLDER=="+newfile);
        try {
            String filePath = newfile.toString() + filename;
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

            //choose another format if PNG doesn't suit you
            imageData.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

            bos.flush();
            bos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.w("TAG", "Error saving image file: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("TAG", "Error saving image file: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: The problem seems to be related to fact that the save path includes `http://..../filename.png` instead of just `/filename.png`